# can not push react git repo on heroku

Tags: reactjs

So I've cloned a github repo on my my own repo and did some edits. I'm trying to deploy it on heroku but I'm encountering errors I don't understand.
Can anyone provide step by step guide to fix the issues? or help me host the project? I'm a total noob at react.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > sqlite3@5.0.2 install /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/sqlite3
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       [sqlite3] Success: "/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote
       
       > nodemon@2.0.7 postinstall /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
       
       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
       
       
       > node-sass@5.0.0 install /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js
       
       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/linux-x64-83_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.Hxxdz/_cacache/node-sass/5.0.0/linux-x64-83_binding.node
       
       > node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js
       
       Binary found at /tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine
       added 1408 packages in 19.854s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build /tmp/build_c9b2026f
       > run-p build:client build:server
       
       
       > show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build:client /tmp/build_c9b2026f
       > npm run webpack -- --mode production
       
       
       > show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build:server /tmp/build_c9b2026f
       > npm run knex -- migrate:latest
       
       
       > show-me-the-money@0.4.0 knex /tmp/build_c9b2026f
       > knex --knexfile ./server/db/knexfile.js "migrate:latest"
       
       
       > show-me-the-money@0.4.0 webpack /tmp/build_c9b2026f
       > webpack --config ./client/webpack.config.js "--mode" "production"
       
       Working directory changed to /tmp/build_c9b2026f/server/db
       Using environment: production
Error: Unable to acquire a connection
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:339:13)
    at Runner.ensureConnection (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:264:8)
    at Runner.run (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:26:12)
    at SchemaBuilder.Target.then (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:22:43)
    at ensureTable (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/table-creator.js:13:6)
    at listCompleted (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/migration-list-resolver.js:12:9)
    at Object.listAllAndCompleted (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/migration-list-resolver.js:28:5)
    at Migrator.latest (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/Migrator.js:64:57)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_c9b2026f/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:171:55)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! show-me-the-money@0.4.0 knex: `knex --knexfile ./server/db/knexfile.js "migrate:latest"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the show-me-the-money@0.4.0 knex script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Hxxdz/_logs/2021-07-20T09_05_44_051Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build:server: `npm run knex -- migrate:latest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Hxxdz/_logs/2021-07-20T09_05_44_110Z-debug.log
ERROR: "build:server" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build: `run-p build:client build:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the show-me-the-money@0.4.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Hxxdz/_logs/2021-07-20T09_05_44_162Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is link to my repo https://github.com/OsamaB7/Bartering